# How to make seeking on click time bar in jw_player v.6 when use primary flash version?

Tags: php, flash, video, jwplayer

What is function to make `jw_player 6` or `5` seeking when use `flash` version ?

How can to make seek in `( jw_player 6 )` flash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jwplayer 6 you can use js api `jwplayer().seek(position)`